# How I can scan CNIC (ID CARD) in Android studio java

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am building an android app, so I need to scan id card to get name, date of birth, gender, address what should I do?

Android app to scan any identity card and get useful data from id card and need to fill in android app.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can use, I am using firebase automl, If you need to detect specific card like Pakistani Id Card go to auto ml/ vision and provide data set that will create a model can be in tensorflow lite that can be used directly in mobile apps, Or you can get files which can be deployed on server and you can consume rest APIs
[Check this out](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/digidukaan-8af17/ml/automl)

[this link will guide you how to deploy it on server although this will be deprecated  soon you can get vertex AI link from that page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial?_ga=2.78027284.-1214327626.1662035357&amp%3B_gac=1.125661688.1677067924.Cj0KCQiArsefBhCbARIsAP98hXTFdhCR0iTyW8vN-qqSj5UHzHkzY_Gl98kz_rLgUdg7p3x_Z3aVib0aAucmEALw_wcB)

above info was to detect either its a specific card or not.
Next part is to extract data from provided image
for this purpose use  ML kit Text Recognization
[MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition)
this link will guide you how to extract texts from image.